# Is it possible to merge a normal drive and RPN SAN?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, raid

I have two physical drives mounted as Raid 0 mounted on `/data`

I have another RPN San drive mounted on `srv`

is it possible in one way or another to merge that srv with the /data in a sort of software raid? Would the performance take a huge hit making it not worth it?

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.

(I was thinking of putting this on the Unix SE but thought this might be more appropriate. If it is not please shout!)

Comment: Advisable? If you glue _sda_ and _sdb_ and the SAN drive together as one very large RAID-0, if anything happens to any of the three, all your data go to Data Heaven. I would not do it.

Comment: So what you're saying is it is possible? :D